# Get the order id in woocommerce_new_order hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

why don't can get id order in new order ?

This code don't work

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'get_order_details_woo',  1, 1  );
function get_order_details_woo ($order_id)
{

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item_values):

        $item_id = $item_values->get_id();

        $item_data = $item_values->get_data();

        $product_name = $item_data['name'];

        //echo $product_name;
    endforeach;

}
```

But this code is work

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'get_order_details_woo',  1, 1  );

    function get_order_details_woo ()
    {

        $order = wc_get_order( 100);

        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item_values):


            $item_data = $item_values->get_data();

            $product_name = $item_data['name'];

            //echo $product_name;
endforeach;

    }
```

How get id in new order ?

Get new order details if i don't have order id ?

Comment: If you look [**to the source code**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order_Data_Store_CPT.html#88), the `$order_id` **is included in the hooked function as an argument**, just like in **your first code**. So the problem is something else… **Why are you using this code? and for what?**

Answer (score 0):

You get the order ID with this hook, but it seems that the order is just created at this moment with no product items yet. You can check this with var_dump.

try another hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'get_order_details_woo',  1, 1  );
```

this one is fired just after the order object gets it's data and before it is saved to the database. You don't have to retrieve the order ID here, because you get the order object directly.

Answer (score 0):

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'get_order_details_woo', 10, 2 );
function get_order_details_woo($order_id, $data) {
}